# I got a problem when I try to Scrape Whole-food product data with Python by using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

By use following code, I got the output
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/full/path/to/chromedriver')

Product Name: USDA INSPECTED BEEF RIBEYE STEAK*

Product Price:

I am very confused that why product price is empty and it should be 9.98
here is the element "span class="price__value">$9.98</span"

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


# Navigate to the wholefood product page
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/full/path/to/chromedriver')
url = 'https://wildforkfoods.com/products/usda-inspected-beef-ribeye-steak?region_id=990300&gclid=CjwKCAjwoIqhBhAGEiwArXT7K5X1qBn9wREml7UC643CTfsmyPI5ctxRMzRe3FA2To7CddZf43dnCBoC7lYQAvD_BwE&variant=9385081438244'
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(5)

# Extract the relevant product data
product_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h1[text()="USDA Inspected Beef Ribeye Steak*"]')
product_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="price__value"]')


# Print the product data
print('Product Name:', product_name.text)
print('Product Price:', product_price.text)

data = {'Product Name': [product_name.text], 'Product Price': [product_price.text]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save the data to a csv file
df.to_csv('product_data.csv', index=False)

# Close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

I want to know the reason why I got empty and how can I improve it.

Comment: There are two spans of class `price__value` on that page, one with the "compare at" price, which is $0.00.  Are you LOOKING at the page you're trying to parse?

Comment: Yes, that a little bit make sense. So, How can I avoid the one with the "compare at" price. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Anything with character or symbols / etc, you can extract innerHtml like so :

```
product_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h1[text()="USDA Inspected Beef Ribeye Steak*"]')
product_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="price__value"]')

product_price_innerHtml = product_price.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

[Look at the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3unE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try with this XPath of span. I think your XPath is incorrect.

   product_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ProductForm"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[2]/span[2]/span[3]')

Comment: Thank you so much this working. May I ask you why the Xpath should like [@id="ProductForm"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[2]/span[2]/span[3]') rather than what I write. Thank you.

Comment: I think there are several elements that have the XPath what you use.`//span[@class="price__value"]`
I copied the XPath from the chrome-dev-tools.